# Google Maps 2.0 API Issues

Tags: c#, google-maps

The Google Maps API was updated on 2/17 and has caused some issues for me. I help maintain several legacy application that aren't being actively developed, but are still being used. After the update a bunch of them stopped working properly. The main problem was a pretty easy fix. Most of them did not specify a specific version so they were using the experimental branch. I was able to target 3.19 and they started working again.

My bigger problem is with an application that is still using API version 2.0. I know it is recommended to upgrade to version 3.0, but like I said, this application is just being maintained. It was working so there was no reason to spend the time to update it. After the latest update it has stopped working.

I know that when they pulled the plug on API 2.0 they left a wrapper around 3.0 for legacy use. Does anyone know if this has been changed with the latest update? Is it possible to target the version of API 3 that the wrapper uses? Has anyone else seen similar issues with the update?

Here is the code that is failing

```
    function loadMap() {

    try 
    {

        mmap = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"), { draggableCursor: 'crosshair', draggingCursor: 'move' });
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

    }
    catch (Error) {
        mmap = null;

        return "NG";
    }

    mmap.setCenter(new GLatLng(0, 0), 2);
    mmap.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    mmap.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    mmap.enableScrollWheelZoom();
    mmap.enableDoubleClickZoom();
    mmap.enableContinuousZoom();

    return "OK";
```

I am calling this from a .NET application and it is returning null.

```
 Object something = wb.Document.InvokeScript("loadMap");
```

It probably just needs to be updated to v3, but I don't know why it has worked all this time and then suddenly stopped.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution after doing some more digging. It seems to be a combination of a bug and the WebBrowser control. With the latest version the API breaks in IE compatibility mode. Google has confirmed this bug and are working on a fix. Evidently the WebBrowser control must run in compatibility mode and causes the bug.

I was able to fix it by adding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of the page and

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

inside the head tag.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7675